# JavaScript, JSON and Angular JS in sublime text editor 3

Tags: angularjs, sublimetext3

How to add/select syntax in sublime text editor 3 for Angular JS? What are the differences of them?

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a data container.  You use JSON to get data from one place to another.

JavaScript is a scripting language. You write code in JavaScript to perform tasks.

Angular JS is essentially a library of tools, written in JavaScript.  Google runs the Angular development team.  There are many other libraries written in JavaScript, like jQuery and React, for example. The advantage of using a library is that a lot of mundane tasks have been written for you, and this helps reduce the time it takes to write applications.

Answer (score 0):

The extension for AngularJS is .js. AngularJS is not a programming language, it is just a set of tools to make js easier.
If you don't know what a library is, maybe that's the problem. You can see a library as a set of functions that simplifies a work.
Your programs are not written in AngularJS, your programs use AngularJS.
AngularJS is written in JS.
I'm trying to explain my self for you to understand this concepts but my English is not to fluid. However I think the best answer for your question is Delosos's answer above.
For this reason you're not going to be able to select syntax for AngularJS, although there may be some extensions that autocomplete functions of AngularJS.